# How to scroll down vboxmanage output?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, output

When I type the `vboxmanage` command I get a sort of manpage output, where it shows all the information at once. How can I view the info incrementally like less/more commands with files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing just `vboxmanage` will give the help page output to stdout - if this on a TTY etc, you won't be able to scroll it. To make it work like `man`, you can pipe the output to `less`:

```
vboxmanage | less
```

Then you can 'scroll' it with arrow keys/page keys/home or end/mouse wheel/whatever. You can pipe it to `more` as well, but `less` is <del>'nicer'</del> 'easier' to use.

Comment: Thanks Wilf! Im quit new to linux, still have to find my way around .